# How to restrain the arbor on a circular saw to change the blade

Tags: circular-saw

Been trying to change blades on my B&D circular saw But as I try to fasten it the whole thing turns,Seems like the arbor is loose,What could be the problem and can it be fixed?.....Thanks guys.

Comment: FYI there is a woodworking.stackExchange.com for question specifically for woodworking.

Answer (score 7):

Most circular saws have either a push lever that stops the arbor from spinning or a hole in the rear guard through which you insert a thin round metal object (screwdriver) which will catch on a saw blade tooth to keep it from spinning while you tighten the arbor nut.

Note that many saws have a left-hand thread arbor nut.